# Correcting argument for Prove/Disprove any set of non-intersecting figures of 8 in the plane is countable

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

So I was looking at the question above. There was a pre-question which was the same for circles, but I believe this is easy to prove uncountable by considering circles $C_{r} $ of radius r centred at the origin, and $S= \{ C_{r} : r \in \mathbb{R} \} $.

I tried a similar technique for this question- Consider a figure of 8 on the x axis lying horizontally with most -ve x point going through origin. Now we can construct 'concentric' figures of 8 containing one another, each of which has most -ve x point going through a different real, from 0 to -ve infinity. (i.e. let $F_{r} $ be figure of 8 with most -ve x point going through r, and if $s>r$ , $F_{r}$ contains $F_{s}$.

So if this is a fair argument, its clear none of them intersect. But I came across this question here [Countable or uncountable set 8 signs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78018/countable-or-uncountable-set-8-signs) where the answer is it must be countable.

**So what is incorrect with my solution?**

[image: Consider the set of $F_{r}$ for all $r<0$]

Comment: What does "with most -ve x point going through origin" mean?

Comment: You will have problems managing the right ends of your eights

Comment: @lulu Imagine drawing an infinity symbol, with the far most left point going through point (0,0). All other figures of 8 contain this one, and have left most point going through (k,0) for k<0

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ok, please can you explain what you mean? I just thought we could stretch the next figure of 8 in the sequence enough so that it encompasses all previous figures, and we can do this as the x axis is infinitely long. So is the problem that the length of $F_{r}$ tends to infinity as r tends to infinity?

Comment: Ok...but your post refers to "-ve x point" which isn't defined.  "-ve" isn't even a word.  Can you edit your post to include actual definitions?  I also think a picture would be good.

Comment: @lulu Ok, but isnt it well known that "-ve" means negative??

Comment: I've never seen it before, for what that's worth.  But include a picture.  The only way I know to make "concentric" figure $8's$ is to put each successor inside one of the loops of the predecessor.  Otherwise, they have to intersect.

Answer (score 1):

If $F_r$ is one of your figure eights, its righthand loop defines an open interval $I_r$ on the $x$-axis between the crossover point of the $8$ and its most positive point on the $x$-axis. These open intervals are clearly pairwise disjoint and non-empty. But any family of non-empty open intervals of real numbers is necessarily countable, as each must contain a different rational number, and there are only countably many rational numbers. Thus, you can’t build an uncountable nested family of the kind that you’re describing.